# How to buy both USDT and ETH in Token Presale?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc20, bep20

I have created an ERC20 token. I want to create a new contract called Presale and collect it here presale. The token can be purchased on both ETH and USDT.
There is one problem.

How can I set up selling with both ETH and USDT. So if the token price is 0.1USDT, if the person makes the payment with ETH, do I have to calculate it based on the ETH price over solidity?

What should the process be like here?
Thanks.

I tried the Binance Smart Contract library and created the token. I'm not sure how to presale